# How to get next row in MySQL when sorted by order column but with possibility of data change in time?

Tags: php, mysql

OK, my problem is little bit specific and harder to explain. So I will try to simplify as much as possible.

I have MySQL table with "hints" that are beeing shown on website. These hints are ordered by int in column "order". So table looks like this: id(int autoincrement), hint (varchar), order(int).

Now when first hint is displayed to user, it is displayed until user acknowledges it and then next hint is displayed and so on.

I came up with query, which gets me next hint based on which hint specific user acknowledged last time:

```
SELECT hint FROM hints WHERE `order` > $last_seen_item_order ORDER BY `order` DESC LIMIT 1
```

This works fine. However we also need to add sometimes new hint and it's not usually added as the last hint but somewhere in between. So for example, user has seen last hint with order #6, but we added new hint at position e.g. #3. And it will never be displayed to this user, because we have saved for him that he has seen hint #6.

Is there a way how to manage this ? Possible with only by one or two MySQL queries ?

Thank you for any help and hints in advance.

**EDIT:** Each user has its own "seen-state". We keep that simply in PHP $_SESSION['last_seen_item_order']

Comment: i think that you can set id in your table hints to identified user. In your query select all hint from this user. Maybe i understan very well your question, but i think that the most easy it´s set id user in your table

Comment: Not sure I completely understand but why not have a true/false flag `viewed` then you can explicitely show only the last hint that has *not* been seen.

Comment: Add another table, something like `hints_seen` containing `id, hint_id, user_id`. When a user sees a hint, add a record in that table with the hint id and user id. When you then select hints, you can fetch the first in order that doesn't exist for that user in that table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't manage it by this logic.

For this, you need to maintain an extra column - `seen`
You can set this to `1` if the user have seen the `hints`
So your query would be -

```
SELECT 
   hint 
FROM
  hints 
WHERE 
  `order` > last_seen_item_order
   OR seen = 0 
ORDER BY 
   CASE WHEN `order` > last_seen_item_order THEN `order` END DESC
   CASE WHEN `order` <= last_seen_item_order THEN `id` END ASC
LIMIT 1
```

**NOTE** -  This is my suggestion for doing that way.You can have number of ideas of doing it.

**Edit** -
If you want to maintain user wise hints, then you probably have 2 options to maintain `seen`.

1. Store user wise `json` for hints seen by user.
2. Make a separate table `user_hints_see`  with columns `id`(Autoincrement), `user_id`, `hint_id`, `seen`.

Comment: How would you know which users has seen the hints if you only have a single boolean?

Comment: He didn't mention in question about how he is managing users from a single order

Comment: Sure, but it would be pretty strange if they wanted to build something like this but only let the first person accessing the site to see the hints.

Comment: Well , I don't know why he didn't mentioned about user logic of hints, he only mentioned 3 columns.

Comment: I wanted to keep the question simple. Truth is that this wouldn't work for me, because each user must see his own hints based on what he had seen before. We keep this information simply in PHP session like e.g. $_SESSION['last_seen_item_order'] = 6;

Comment: Check the edited answer